# form should not clean if validation failed in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am new to Codeigniter.
today my company give me a task make registration form with full of validation.
I have done all validation.
but new task is that if any validation failed, then form should not cleanup their values it must be filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set_value('val') for the input value:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" />
```

You can find some more guidance on it here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Comment: Ohh super dude.
Thank u very much.
Muwaahhhh